# Hyperlink downloads whatever that img src is

Tags: javascript, image, dom, download

Alright i can't really seem to find anything regarding EXACTLY what i'm doing.

Anyways i need to set a hyperlink to download an image. That image has an id already.

Everytime the user displays an image, the download link will download that image they have entered.

When you run the code, enter 255812 for image code.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imagetxt").value;
  var y = "http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-" + x + ".jpg";

  // Creating an image
  var img = new Image();

  // Defining the function if image loads successfully.
  img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = y;
  };

  //Defining the function if image fails to load.
  img.onerror = function() {
    alert("Image not found");
  };
  img.src = y;
}
```

```html
<body align="center">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXo8Fxp.png" width="20%" height="20%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jCOLCiU.png" width="8%" height="8%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="imagetxt" size="6" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Display" onclick="myFunction()" style="top: 5px; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="image1" src="" width="30%" height="30%" style="top: 10px; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <a href="???" id="imageDL" onclick="??">DOWNLOAD THIS</a>
```

Comment: Do produce the effect desired, point the url to that of the file to be downloaded. Change the `location` variable in JavaScript to that of the absolute url of the file you wish to download.

Comment: FYI `align` is seriously deprecated.

Comment: @www139 Thats what i do not know how to do. change the url location with javascript.

Comment: I'm currently experimenting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the onclick on the anchor tag

```
 <a href="#" id="imageDL" download>DOWNLOAD THIS</a>
```

Set the anchor's href in the img.onload

```
img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = y;
    document.getElementById("imageDL").href = y;
};
```

Comment: Now all i need to do is set a download name. I tired doing download="name1" but that didn't work out.

Comment: I have also tried

document.getElementById("imageDL").download = "name";

Comment: If the image comes from a different domain, chrome does not allow you to set the name with the download attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of `myFunction`

```
document.getElementById("imageDL").href = y;
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imagetxt").value;
  var y = "http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-" + x + ".jpg";

  // Creating an image
  var img = new Image();

  // Defining the function if image loads successfully.
  img.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("image1").src = y;
  };

  //Defining the function if image fails to load.
  img.onerror = function() {
    alert("Image not found");
  };
  img.src = y;
  
  document.getElementById("imageDL").href = y;
}
```

```html
<body align="center">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/dXo8Fxp.png" width="20%" height="20%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jCOLCiU.png" width="8%" height="8%">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="imagetxt" size="6" type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Display" onclick="myFunction()" style="top: 5px; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img id="image1" src="" width="30%" height="30%" style="top: 10px; position: relative;">
  </div>
  <a href="???" id="imageDL" onclick="??">DOWNLOAD THIS</a>
```

Comment: I just ran your code snippet.. all it did was enlarge the image to full screen.